# In the following code how is Database class automatically instantiated?

Tags: python

```
from abc import *

class Myclass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def connect(self):
        pass
    
    @abstractmethod
    def disconnect(self):
        pass

class Oracle(Myclass):
    def connect(self):
        print("Connecting to Oracle database")
    
    def disconnect(self):
        print("Disconnecting fron Oracle")

class Sybase(Myclass):
    def connect(self):
        print("Connecting to Sybase database")
    
    def disconnect(self):
        print("Disconnecting fron Sybase")

class Database:
    str = input("Enter database name: ")
    classname = globals()[str]
    obj = classname()
    obj.connect()
    obj.disconnect()
```

When the code is run, why is "Enter database name: " displayed in terminal? shouldn't this happen after a object of class Database is create?

Comment: The code asking for input is in the class *body*, not any instance *method*. No `Database` object is ever created; the class is entirely useless.

Comment: You have an `input` statement in the _definition_ of the `Database` class. Initialisation happens in the `__init__` method.

Comment: You're wrong, you're not getting an instance of Database; when python is looking at your code to load available class names and function names into context, it scans your code line by line. So happens that your input is called as part of python reading your Database class. If you want to avoid this, put it in a function. Also your code is very hard to follow. Maybe you want Database to be a function instead of a class?